# Why does a printf() stop a crash from occuring?

Tags: debugging, visual-c++

I have been looking all over the Internet for an answer to this question (see subject of post). I have been asked this exact question twice. Once at an interview for company  and once by a friend and I cannot find the answer for the life of me.

I have actually experienced this error on multiple occasions when debugging without a debugger, and just using print statements to isolate the error. I cannot recall any exact situations, though I am positive I have experienced it. If anyone can provide a link or a reference or point me to something in printf() source that might cause an error to stop occurring when using print statements to debug code I would greatly appreciate the good read.

Thank you,
Matthew Hoggan

I am currently reading the link provided but for further conversation I have posted some of my weak attempts to investigate:

Okay, so i have started to play around myself to try and answer my own question but things are still not 100% clear to me. Below is the output from the g++ compiler using the -S option to output the assembly instead of the executable. The equivalent C++ code is also posted below. My goal is to try and recreate a simple scenario and then try and detect based on the instructions what might be happening at the processor levels. So lets say right after the "call printf" assembly code, which I am assuming is linked from the library files stored in /usr/lib or another lib directory, I tried to access a NULL pointer (not in code), or some other form of operation that would traditionally crash the program. I am assuming that I would have to find out what printf is doing instruction wise to get a deeper look into this?

```
.file   "assembly_test_printf.cpp"

        .section    .rodata

.LC0:

    .string "Hello World"

    .text

.globl main

    .type   main, @function

main:

.LFB0:

    .cfi_startproc

    .cfi_personality 0x0,__gxx_personality_v0

    pushl   %ebp

    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 8

    movl    %esp, %ebp

    .cfi_offset 5, -8

    .cfi_def_cfa_register 5

    andl    $-16, %esp

    subl    $32, %esp

    movl    $0, 28(%esp)

    movl    $.LC0, (%esp)

    call    printf

    movl    28(%esp), %eax

    leave

    ret

    .cfi_endproc

.LFE0:

    .size   main, .-main

    .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.4.4-14ubuntu5) 4.4.5"

    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

Equivalent C++ code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ( int argc, char** argv ) {

    int x = 0;

    printf ("Hello World"); 

    return x;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are  several reasons adding a `printf()` can change the behavior of a bug. Some of the more common ones might be:

- changing the timing of execution (particularly for threading bugs)
- changing memory use patterns (the compiler might change how the stack is used)
- changing how registers are used

For example, an uninitialized local variable might be allocated to a register.  Before adding the `printf()` the uninitialized variable is used and gets come garbage value that's in the register (maybe the result of a previous call to `rand()`, so it really is indeterminate).  Adding the `printf()` causes the register to be used in `printf()` and `printf()` always happens to leave that register set to `0` (or whatever).  Now your buggy program is still bugy, but with different behavior. And maybe that behavior happens to be benign.

Comment: In addition to what Michael Burr has said, see this article on the disadvantages of using printf() as the debugging method: http://www.oopweb.com/CPP/Documents/DebugCPP/Volume/techniques.html

Comment: thank you for the good read yasouser. I have applied a few of these debugging techniques before. I tend to favor non-buffered output like streams if I do output debugging. I have only been programming for about 3 years now, and when I first started is when I ran into the "printf()" error.

Comment: Another thing is that 'printf' is a function call that the compiler knows nothing about. So the compiler assumes that it might modify any variable whose address could potentially be known to it. This means register copies are flushed before the call to 'printf' and reloaded after it. This can cause significant behavior differences in multi-threaded code. (It acts like a memory barrier.)

Answer (score 1):

I've seen it before, for example in Java, in cases where initialization code isn't complete when another thread attempts to access an object assumed to have already been created. The System.out.println() slows down the other thread enough for the initialization to complete.